# gotoAndStop Wont work?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, timeline

I am trying to jump from one movieclip to a frame within other movieclip by using gotoAndStop.

But when using gotoAndStop the movieclip just disapears? 
When i change it to gotoAndPlay it jumps to the correct frame but plays the movieclip and dont want this i want it to stop?

```
angZoom_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoomOut);

function zoomOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.parent.getChildByName('ZoomOutAngles_mc')).visible = false;
    MovieClip(this.parent).spin_Y.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

I cant understand why it works with gotoAndplay but not GotoAndStop?

Comment: So, if you change `gotoAndStop(1)` to `gotoAndPlay(1)`, it works? Then make sure there is something on the sprite when you are on frame 1. Check the timeline of your movieclip.

Comment: strange there is something on frame 1 but just changed it to frame 2 and it worked? ummm?

Comment: I have another movieclip that needs to be linked to the last frame of this movieclip also and its doing the same? For some reason its not registering the first and last frame even though they are there? Strange, ill check the rest of my code.

Comment: Is it because on frame one and frame 11 they contain another movieclip? Ive tried putting

Comment: MovieClip(this.parent).spin_Y.AWComplete_mc.gotoAndStop; But this didnt work either?

Comment: Could you upload a picture of your timeline somewhere?

Comment: Its Ok ive sussed it, I had the mc set at visible = false. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: By checking that I had something on the frame i was targeting and correcting code else where that made this frame invisible i solved this problem.

Comment: I ment as a real answer instead of a comment to the question :D

Answer (score 0):

By checking that I had something on the frame i was targeting and correcting code else where that made this frame invisible i solved this problem.